# In this case, why 1 byte extra when computing the file size?

Tags: c, linux, windows, size

I made this following observations after making a text file on Ubuntu 12.10 through GUI (alt+enter) as well as in Terminal (ls -l).

- when file was empty : file size = 0 byte.
- when one character  : file size = 2 bytes.
- when two characters : file size = 3 bytes.

Why 1 byte extra when the file just contains one character, i know this is not because of End-Of-File because when i wrote a c program the loop terminated when it reached End-Of-File and it gave me the same results, so obviously this doesn't count, then what is it?

But on windows when the file contained one character the file size was just 1 byte, it was normal. What are the things behind all this stuffs?

Comment: Which GUI editor are you using? It may add a terminating newline! Use the `od` command to find out.

Comment: 8 upvotes and 2000 views and this is closed as being unlikely to help future visitors...

Comment: @duhaime I voted it to reopen. You too please vote. May be we can get better answers!

Answer (score 15):

It's due to text editor you are getting this.
YOu must have pressed extra terminating character such as newline.

If you want `1 byte` size for 1 character in a file.

Just do like this on you terminal.

```
#cat > file // create a file for input
x{CTRL+D}  // after inputting one character 'x' , press CTRL+D twice
           // one for terminating file and one for killing the cat process.

#ls -l  // list the file
```

You will get exactly `1` byte file size.

Try it. (It's working on my system Ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: It worked, and this solved my one more doubt. So "cat file" won't force the prompt on a new line since this file doesn't contain the newline character. Thank you and everyone for the reply. have a great day.

Comment: @dimSutar :  Until unless you give newline it wont read automatically. You are welcome anytime. You can accept the answer if agreed.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely the extra character is the newline character at the end of each line in a Unix/Linux text file. You should be able to see that char using the command 'od -c file'.

Comment: In unix, echo -n "TEXT" > "FILENAME" -> will avoid adding new line character.