# Why is a text file containing only the word "hello" 6 (and not 5) bytes in size?

Tags: file, byte

As I understand it, one character is one byte in size. As a test, I made (using Gedit) two text files, one called `hello.txt` containing only the word "hello", and similarly, one called `goodbye.txt` containing only the word "goodbye". This is how they look with `ls -lhtr`:

[image]

It would appear that `hello.txt`, which contains 5 characters, is 6 bytes in size, and `goodbye.txt`, which contains 7 characters, is 8 bytes in size. To generalize, it seems like a file with `n` characters is `n+1` bytes large. Can someone explain to me where the extra byte comes from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In this case, why 1 byte extra when computing the file size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717523/in-this-case-why-1-byte-extra-when-computing-the-file-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your editor is most likely inserting a newline character into the file. On Linux, that would be a one byte '\n' (newline) character. On some OSes, that would be the two byte sequence '\r\n' (carriage return, newline).

Check the file contents with:
`od -c <filename>`

That will show the byte-by-byte contents.

Answer (score -2):

yes, in character strings on byte is use for null (/0) for termnating the string so its byte is always greater than original array length..

Comment: While a null terminator is used in some languages such as C, I don't think I've ever seen a text editor that terminates a file with a null.